# Should you run chkdsk to repair two problematic .docx files?

Tags: microsoft-word, chkdsk, file-recovery

I have two problematic .docx files.

After opening the file:

[image: After opening the file]

After clicking Yes:

[image: After clicking Yes]

Tried all four methods of [this part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/damaged-documents-in-word#troubleshooting-steps-to-try-if-the-damaged-document-does-not-open) of the troubleshooting guide from Microsoft. None worked.

One solution from the Web is to run chkdsk. However, I've read about instances where chkdsk made things worse by corrupting more files and damaging the overall health of a hard drive (I'm using an SSD). Should I run chkdsk to repair the two .docx files?

Comment: Have you tried to go to File Explorer > Right-click these two files > Property, check whether there is "Unblock"option? If yes, you may click it.

Comment: There's no Unblock option.

Comment: If all fails, rename the .docx to .zip, then you can manually extract the content and dig through the raw content. You will most likely not be able to recover the formatting, but I saved many documents using this method when the automated tools failed.

Comment: @Papooch I have tried that, but my document can't be archived. It could be because it's password-protected.

Answer (score 6):

I would not use CHKDSK as it may damage the logical document when it puts good sectors together. CHKDSK is a file system repair only.

Use Word Repair to repair Word documents.

This is much better than repairing with CHKDSK and stands a better chance of recovering your document.

**If the documents cannot be repair with Word Repair, then you may need to recover from a backup or re-create the documents.**

[Word Document Repair](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-a-document-after-a-file-corruption-error-47df9d48-2165-4411-a699-1786ac734bc3)

> Click File > Open > Browse and then go to the location or folder where
> the document (Word), workbook (Excel), or presentation (PowerPoint) is
> stored. *Don't try to open the file from the Recent section as this
> won't go into the Open dialog box.*   **You need to open from the file
> location.**
>
> Click the file you want, and then click the arrow next to Open, and
> click Open and Repair.

Here is a screen shot

[image]

Comment: +1 Emphasis on the fact that chkdsk's job is to fix the filesystem. It doesn't give a damn about your files & will sacrifice them completely to be able to do its job… fix the filesystem. For some reason people seem to think it's there to fix your files. It's not.

Comment: Tried that already but didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: In that case, then. you will need to recover the document from a backup (if you have one), or re-create the document.

Comment: @John I can't re-create the document because the content is not something one can memorize or that can be looked up in the Web. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: This is now the time to set up backups so that if the same thing happens in the future, you can restore lost or broken documents.

Comment: @John The files are backed up in OneDrive. I can use Version History, but I won't recover my most recent changes.

Comment: That is probably the best you can do at this point. Hopefully you can recall the most recent changes. Good luck.